# calculate average from values in map in scala

Tags: scala, hashmap

I have a map that represents a gradebook where the key is the grade and the value is the number of students who achieved that grade.

my map looks like this:

```
grades = Map("1" -> 0, "2" -> 0, "3" -> 0, "4" -> 0, "5" -> 0)
```

then i read the values for the keys from a list of students with their grades, filling the 0s with values.

what i want to do now is calculate the average grade:

```
val avg = grades.foreach{case (k,v) => k * v} / grades.foldLeft(0)(_+_._2)
```

but the problem is that

```
grades.foreach{case (k,v) => k * v}
```

only returns `()`.

Comment: `grades.foldLeft(0)(_+_._2)` -> `grades.values.sum`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try: (there are other methods to do this - I'm trying to stick with your original flow)

```
val avg =  grades.map{case (k,v) => k.toInt * v}.sum 
         / grades.foldLeft(0)(_+_._2).toFloat
```

my alterations to your code: 
1. use map and not foreach
2. cast k into integer 
3. divide by float to get float answer

Comment: glad to be of help. please consider accepting my answer :)